# Can I safely remove ASP .NET MVC 2 from Visual Studio if I use ASP .NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to speed up my computer a little bit, and apart from [these useful tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) I'm trying to remove all Visual Studio extensions and add-ins that I don't use anymore.

I noticed I have both ASP .NET MVC 2 and 3 installed side-by-side, and I don't use version 2 at all.

[image: ASP .NET MVC 2 and 3 side-by-side install]

**Can I safely delete the old version, or does MVC 3 depend on MVC 2?**
I don't want to mess up my working environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.
MVC 2 and MVC 3 are completely independent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I did this myself. In fact when I first installed MVC3 there was a known conflict whereby MVC3 won't work properly unless MVC1 is uninstalled first. Can't remember the details but yes you can remove MVC1 and MVC2 leaving MVC3 intact fine.